# datatable bound to datagridview through bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I have a datagridview on a windows form. I have a bindingsource and datatable which are created at runtime which I intend to use to bind and keep my datagridview updated.

When debugging I see that my datatable is being populated with rows. I can also see my bindingsource's datasource has data when you open the visualizer.

My issue is that my datagridview stays blank and never seems to get any of the data that my datatable and bindingsource are getting.

Code Sample:

```
 Private bs1 As New BindingSource
 Private TraysToScanDatatable As New DataTable
```

in my constructor

```
TraysToScanDatatable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("time", GetType(DateTime)))
TraysToScanDatatable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("scanner", GetType(Integer)))
TraysToScanDatatable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("traynumber", GetType(Integer)))
bs1.DataSource = TraysToScanDatatable
UpdateDataGridView(TraysToReadDataGridView, bs1.DataSource) 'if I do not set my datagridview with a delegate here then I cannot update the binding source in the timer.
```

update timer logic

```
  TraysToScanDatatable.Rows.Add(New Object() {DateTime.Now, 1, lastScanner1TrayReceived})
  Me.bs1.DataSource = TraysToScanDatatable
  me.bs1.MoveLast
```

and my updatedatagridview routine

```
 Public Sub UpdateDataGridView(ByVal control As DataGridView, ByVal newdata As DataTable)
    If Not control.InvokeRequired Then
        control.DataSource = newdata
    Else
        Invoke(New Action(Of DataGridView, DataTable)(AddressOf UpdateDataGridView), control, newdata)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was multi-part.

I had to assign datagridview's datasource to bindingsource object (instead of bindingsource.datasource) as Carlos Landeras pointed out.

In addition to this I had to call:

```
 bindingsource.ResetBindings(False)
    DataGridView.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the `BindingSource` object itself to the `datagridView.Datasource`
and not the `BindingSource.Datasource`.

This line of yours:

```
If Not control.InvokeRequired Then
    control.DataSource = newdata
Else
```

is assigning `bs1.DataSource` to grid Datasource instead of the `BindingSource object`

Try doing it like this:

```
datagridview.DataSource = bs1
bs1.Datasource = TraysToScanDatatable
```

And if this works, then apply your logic following steps.

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested but when I run it I get the same results.Anything else to check?

Comment: Have you checked while debugging that TraysToScanDatatable has any row when you assign it to bs1.Datasource?. Also use datagridview.AutogenerateColumns = true before the binding

Comment: TraysToScanDatatable has data before the assignment to bs1.datasource. I am also using autogenerate = true. Thanks for your help. From everything I read in tutorials this is all I should need to do to make this work.